# what is the rationale behind having both matrix and array?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I start off with R, and I came across this question when I see the book literally giving example that shows matrix and array are interchangeable (do they really?) if so  what is the rationale behind having both matrix and array?

Comment: Arrays can have more than two dimensions.

Comment: To a certain degree its just nomenclature. Matrices are just arrays that happen to have 2 dimensions. It's just that so much of stats happens with that specific case of "arrays" it's worth splitting it out because it's so common.

Comment: my=matrix(1:20,nrow=4)- what it does then?

Comment: @Explorer_N `my` is just a matrix with four rows and 20 values, i.e., 5 columns.

Comment: "matrix" and "array" are implicit `class`es where any object with `length(dim(.)) == 2L` is `class`ed as a "matrix" and any object with `length(dim(.)) > 0L && length(dim(.)) != 2L` is an "array". Being `class`es means that methods can be created and, also, they can be exploited to be made explicit. So, if -for some reason- a `length(dim()) == 2L` object is explicitly forced as an "array" (`structure(1:6, dim = c(3, 2), class = "array")`) then "matrix" methods won't dispatch on it whereas "array" methods will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of tests:

Here is a 2X2 matrix

```
temp <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
> is.matrix(temp)
[1] TRUE
> is.array(temp)
[1] TRUE
```

Now a 2X2 array:

```
temp2 <- array(0, dim=c(2,2))
> is.matrix(temp2)
[1] TRUE
> is.array(temp2)
[1] TRUE
```

Now let's see if they are the same:

```
> identical(temp, temp2)
[1] TRUE
```

Now, let's look at a 2X2X2 array:

```
temp3 <- array(0, dim=c(2,2,2))
> is.matrix(temp3)
[1] FALSE
> is.array(temp3)
[1] TRUE
```